# Strange behavior using docker

Tags: neo4j

i'm using neo4j with docker.
At the large, the product is running, but I cannot config it.
I added some configs in a neo4j/conf/neo4j.conf (which are ignored|).

This is my launch command:

```
docker run -e NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.\\\* --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --volume=$HOME/arianne/2017/neo4j/data:/data --volume=$HOME/arianne/2017/neo4j/logs:/logs --volume=$HOME/arianne/2017/neo4j/conf:/conf --rm -e NEO4J_AUTH=none --volume=$HOME/arianne/2017/neo4j/plugins:/plugins neo4j:3.2
```

and this is the loading log ...

```
Active database: graph.db
Directories in use:
  home:         /var/lib/neo4j
  config:       /var/lib/neo4j/conf
  logs:         /logs
  plugins:      /plugins
  import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
  data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
  certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /var/lib/neo4j/run
Starting Neo4j.
    2017-07-05 10:18:27.679+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: 
causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address
    2017-07-05 10:18:27.681+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: 
causal_clustering.raft_advertised_address
    2017-07-05 10:18:27.681+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: 
causal_clustering.raft_listen_address
    2017-07-05 10:18:27.681+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: 
ha.host.coordination
2017-07-05 10:18:27.681+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: 
    causal_clustering.transaction_advertised_address
2017-07-05 10:18:27.682+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: 
    causal_clustering.discovery_advertised_address
2017-07-05 10:18:27.682+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: ha.host.data
2017-07-05 10:18:27.682+0000 WARN  Unknown config option: 
    causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address
2017-07-05 10:18:27.717+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.2.1 ========
2017-07-05 10:18:27.918+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, 
    generating a self-signed certificate..
2017-07-05 10:18:28.759+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-07-05 10:18:30.433+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2017-07-05 10:18:40.255+0000 INFO  Started.
2017-07-05 10:18:42.441+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at 
    http://192.168.10.196:7474/
```

The directory are totally different from those I put on the command line, and the directory var/lib/neo4j doesnt exists!!!

Any idea?
Paolo

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
sudo docker run \
-p 7474:7474 \
-p 7687:7687 \
-p 7473:7473 \
-v $HOME/dockerneo4j/data:/data \
-v $HOME/dockerneo4j/logs:/logs \
-v $HOME/dockerneo4j/import:/import \
-v $HOME/dockerneo4j/conf:/conf \
-v $HOME/dockerneo4j/plugins:/plugins \
neo4j:3.2.1
```

The config-file in dockerneo4j/conf is used (easily tested by changing the databasename in there and checking in dockerneo4j/data if a new database folder is created). The apoc plugins are picked up too.

It is correct (although - granted - confusing) that the log shows /var/lib/neo4j directories, those are the internal ones in your docker image.

Hope this helps,
Tom

P.S. http://kvangundy.com/wp/set-up-neo4j-and-docker/ has all the information.